# ListView performance and order of list items android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

It is advised to use **View Recycling** and **View Holder pattern** while using **list view** in our app.But the problem I am facing after using **View Recycling** and **View Holder Pattern** is that when i try to scroll my list view the order of the list items disturbs/changes randomly. I don't know what is happening right now. Searched a lot but find nothing. In a severe need.. please help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Put your code of the adapter pls.

Comment: Here it is.. http://pastie.org/9178742

Comment: suspect #1: loader.displayimage thingy getImage() it might be doing something heavy on the UI thread. Try to comment it out the calls to it to see if it improves.

Comment: I suggest that you remove your first row from the adapter and handle it separately outside the adapter. Insert it on top of the listview so your adapter gets simpler -> less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** You are not creating a new ViewHolder when `convertView` is `null`.

**Second:** You have a ViewHolder instance as a member variable of the class and you continually manipulate this ViewHolder. There should be one ViewHolder instance per row item on screen and you should create and manipulate the ViewHolder **only within getView()*.

Instead of this:

```
private ViewHolder holder;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = ...;
    setData();
}

private void setData() {
    holder.tv_name.setText(...);
    // etc.
}
```

Do this:

```
// no private ViewHolder instance

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = ...; // create new or getTag
    setData(holder);
}

private void setData(ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.tv_name.setText(...);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks @Karakuri..i always do that but here i want to access my holder outside of getView. So what should i do..?

Comment: Why do you want to access the holder outside of getView? Keep in mind you can always get the row's ViewHolder later by calling getTag.

Comment: because i am not doing much code inside my adapter's getView. I have created functions inside my getView and i want to access my list elements attached to holder in that functions. Might be you are saying to pass holder object in my function's argument?

Comment: It's much clearer to people who read your code if you pass it as an argument to the functions and not rely on some variable with larger scope. Also, if you are calling those functions inside of `getView()` and never calling them anywhere else, then that code is effectively still inside of `getView()`.

Comment: hmmm.. you are right. All I was thinking not to mix up my entire code inside getView(). so i have created separate functions. Otherwise it is not bad inside getView() either.